# TYPO3:Typoscript = render temp var

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I have a problem in my Typoscript and can not find nay solution.
Here is an extract of my typoscript :

```
temp.my_class = TEXT
temp.my_class.value = my_custom_class
temp.my_class.wrap = class="|"

10 < styles.content.get

10.select.where = ( deleted = 0 && hidden = 0 && CType = 'image' )
10.select.andWhere = ( tx_gridelements_container = ###whatever### )
10.select.orderBy = sorting ASC
10.select.max = 1
10.select.markers.whatever.field = uid

10.renderObj = FILES
10.renderObj.references.table = tt_content
10.renderObj.references.fieldName = image

10.renderObj.renderObj = IMAGE
10.renderObj.renderObj.file.import.data = file:current:publicUrl
10.renderObj.renderObj.file.width = 200
10.renderObj.renderObj.params.cObject < temp.my_class
```

I use multiple ways but no success (with "lib" instead of "temp", with "=<", with "insertData" method ...) . By the way -> I can't use constants.
Do you have an idea on how to make it ?
Thanks for your help =)

Comment: This won't work. You want to address a TEXT object into a value which only wants a string. TEXT object is NOT a string replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first:
You need to use the copy operator `<` to use some `temp.`-objects.
References (`=<` won't work as `temp.` objects are not available at rendering time, just for the scanning of the typoscript.
And `=` just assigns text and no object.

second:
Remember that `<` only copies the defenition. if you copy an object definition to a simple text attribute you get the name of the object as value.
To avoid this either use `.stdWrap` or `.cObject`.

third:
Use wraps where the value is defined.

In your case it would be something like:

```
temp.my_class = TEXT
temp.my_class.field = my_custom_class
temp.my_class.wrap = class="|"

.... here other lines .....

10.renderObj.renderObj = IMAGE
10.renderObj.renderObj.file.import.data = file:current:publicUrl
10.renderObj.renderObj.file.width = 200
10.renderObj.renderObj.params.cObject < temp.my_class
```

this will result in:

```
10.renderObj.renderObj = IMAGE
10.renderObj.renderObj.file.import.data = file:current:publicUrl
10.renderObj.renderObj.file.width = 200
10.renderObj.renderObj.params.cObject = TEXT
10.renderObj.renderObj.params.cObject.field = my_custom_class
10.renderObj.renderObj.params.cObject.wrap = class="|"
```

---

but I think you really want this (no `cObject`):

```
10.renderObj.renderObj = IMAGE
10.renderObj.renderObj.file.import.data = file:current:publicUrl
10.renderObj.renderObj.file.width = 200
10.renderObj.renderObj.params.field = my_custom_class
10.renderObj.renderObj.params.wrap = class="|"
```

so your extraction of the fieldname with a temp-object (to simulate a constant) would be either:

```
temp.my_class_field = my_custom_class
:
10.renderObj.renderObj.params.field < temp.my_class_field
10.renderObj.renderObj.params.wrap = class="|"
```

or

```
temp.my_class {
    field = my_custom_class
    wrap = class="|"
}
:
10.renderObj.renderObj.params < temp.my_class
```

Comment: Thanks for all these explanations. If I test the first way with "cObject = TEXT", and then "cObject.value = test_class", and then "cObject.wrap = class='|'", -> it works. But if I do "cObject < temp.my_custom_class" it doestn't work anymore... ! I edited my first topic above with more lines by the way.

Comment: The second without cOObject also works if i make it "manually", but as soon as I am trying to copies the defenition with " < temp.my_class" it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: you may inspect your result with the TSOB (TypoScriptObjectBrowser). and make sure `temp.my_class` is defined before it is used: look into the Template Analyzer and view all typoscript to get the order of definition and wether there are conditions or missing brackets, ....

Comment: Here it is : [link](http://nsa39.casimages.com/img/2017/10/10//171010021226245876.jpg) . Blue square = my temp object, green square = image to include the temp as attribute. And I have "10.renderObj.renderObj.params < temp.my_class" !

Comment: As a `temp` object should be top level and it is beyond `renderObj.` I assume you have errors in your braces. defining `temp...` somewhere would be possible, but then you need to specify the correct path to include and you will loose the option to clean up your typoscript before rendering starts.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
10.renderObj.renderObj.params.cObject < tmp.my_class
10.renderObj.renderObj.params.cObject.wrap = class="|"
```

Comment: That doesn't work, maybe i forget to mention it's on a file object -> my first topic is edited if you want to look

Comment: My mistake, I have lost an "b" of "cObject". It should also work on IMAGE Content Objects because "params" of the IMAGE is of type stdWrap so it has an cObject

Comment: OMG of course ! But doesn't work neither. It does if I make "cObject = TEXT" and then "cObject.value = my_custom_class" and "cObject.wrap = class='|' ". But not when using "cObject < tmp.my_class" :(

Comment: Then maybe try to use lib.my_class instead of tmp.my_class

Comment: Same result with "lib"